# Is an open disk complete?

Tags: geometry, surfaces

See the definitionS of complete surface, first definition: without edges. second definition: Any line segment can be continued indefinitely. By the first, open disk seems to be a complete surface, but by the second, it seems not. So if it is complete on earth? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "complete on earth"?

Comment: Also: it sounds like you have some definitions (given in class notes or a textbook, perhaps?) that you are paraphrasing. Can you quote them precisely? It may be that they have some subtleties that make it easier to resolve this apparent conflict.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean by complete.  Here are two possible definitions:

1)  It is [complete as a metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space): every Cauchy sequence converges to a point in the space.

2)  It is [geodesically complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem) - i.e. at each point the exponential map is defined on the whole tangent space at that point.

(By [Hopf-Rinow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem) these two are equivalent.)

However, these definitions don't make sense without a *metric*.  In the former case any metric in the sense of a metric space will do, but for the latter to make sense you probably want a Riemannian metric.  For concreteness let's say we take the metric-space notion for this discussion.

Here are two examples two show why this matters (both will be Riemannian metrics).

Example 1:  The open disc is homeomorphic to R^n, so you may take the standard Euclidean metric on R^n and pull it back to the disc, so that the two are isometric.  With this metric it is complete because it is isometric to a complete space (R^n).

Example 2:  Take the Euclidean metric in R^n and just restrict it to the disc (i.e. the *usual* metric).  This space is *not complete* as above because you may take as a Cauchy sequence any sequence converging to a boundary point, and this sequence fails to converge in the disc.  (Note that in the above example this sequence would not be Cauchy because the metric in that example blows up near the edge of the disc.)  This shows that this metric on the disc is not complete.

You could take as another example the Poincare (hyperbolic) metric on the disc, which is quite different from example 1 (negatively curved) but is also complete.

Comment: Neither of these is equivalent to either the definitions that OP seems to be hinting at: the first being something like "boundaryless" and the second being something like "subspace".

Comment: Agreed, but I couldn't tell what specific definition the OP was getting at, so I tried to suggest something concrete as a starting point.  Maybe OP can provide the concrete definition they had in mind, or you can propose a better definition and answer based on that?  However I note that "boundaryless" alone isn't usually enough to decide, as the examples provided should clarify.

Comment: The definition is from stillwell's geometry of surface, also you can google complete surface.

Comment: @Joseph Then please edit your question - give the definition of complete surface from Stillwell as part of the question.

Comment: @amomin：The definition of complete surface from Stillwell is: Any line segment can be continued indefinitely.(Same words)